# What interface or abstract class does XmlSerializer implement

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control

I cannot seem to find this on google, msdn, or on SO. I am trying to find out what interface or abstract class that `XmlSerializer` implements.

Is there a shared interface that `XmlSerializer`, `BinaryFormatter` and `SOAPFormatter` all implement? (I am aware that `BinaryFormatter` and `SOAPFormatter` both use `IFormatter`, but `XmlSerializer` does not).

I am trying to create a generic method:

```
public byte[] To(Type t) {
```

where i pass the type of one of the above which then uses Activator to create an instance of the formatter/serializer to serialize the object.

Comment: Any particular reason why? Why not define your own abstraction layer or interface/wrappers around the serializers? EDIT: Also "no", `XmlSerializer` inherits directly from `object` and implements no interfaces.

Comment: i would rather not have to have unnecessary code to complete something that the language may be able to do without anything extra

Comment: You _could_ cast them as `dynamic` and call the same methods... I don't recommend it though. EDIT: _And_ in addition `XmlSerializer` does not have a public parameterless constructor for you to instantiate with unlike the `BinaryFormatter` and `SOAPFormatter`. So no matter what you'd have diverging/different code handling the cases -- you may as well write a _simple_ serialization/deserialization wrapper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid the answer is none. Here is its declaration from decompiled source:

```
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public class XmlSerializer
{
...
```